Bncert renewal failed with TLS handshake error
My Let's Encrypt cert expired and I went to try and renew it using 'sudo /opt/bitnami/bncert-tool'. It rolls through domains, contact email and confirmation. When it runs an error comes up (paste below). Any suggestions welcome!
It's on AWS Lightsail, Bitnami, Apache
 

An error occurred renewing certificates with Let's Encrypt:


2024/06/15 13:13:12 [INFO] [gymist.co.uk] acme: Trying renewal with -29 hours 
remaining
2024/06/15 13:13:12 [INFO] [gymist.co.uk, www.gymist.co.uk] acme: Obtaining 
bundled SAN certificate
2024/06/15 13:13:13 [INFO] [gymist.co.uk] AuthURL: 
https://acme-v02.api.letsencrypt.org/acme/authz-v3/363352580177
2024/06/15 13:13:13 [INFO] [www.gymist.co.uk] AuthURL: 
https://acme-v02.api.letsencrypt.org/acme/authz-v3/364283107647
2024/06/15 13:13:13 [INFO] [gymist.co.uk] acme: authorization already valid; 
skipping challenge
2024/06/15 13:13:13 [INFO] [www.gymist.co.uk] acme: use tls-alpn-01 solver
2024/06/15 13:13:13 [INFO] [www.gymist.co.uk] acme: Trying to solve TLS-ALPN-01
2024/06/15 13:13:22 http: TLS handshake error from 152.37.68.88:38421: tls: 
client requested unsupported application protocols ([h2 http/1.1])
2024/06/15 13:13:22 http: TLS handshake error from 152.37.68.88:39202: tls: 
client requested unsupported application protocols ([h2 http/1.1])
2024/06/15 13:13:22 http: TLS handshake error from 152.37.68.88:37443: tls: 
client requested unsupported application protocols ([h2 http/1.1])
2024/06/15 13:13:22 http: TLS handshake error from 152.37.68.88:40238: tls: 
Press [Enter] to continue:
client requested unsupported application protocols ([h2 http/1.1])
2024/06/15 13:13:22 http: TLS handshake error from 152.37.68.88:40239: tls: 
client requested unsupported application protocols ([h2 http/1.1])
2024/06/15 13:13:22 http: TLS handshake error from 152.37.68.88:37574: tls: 
client requested unsupported application protocols ([h2 http/1.1])




Tried removing the existing certs but this created other problems, so rolled it back.

